# mock.patch() not patching class who called a couples of levels inside function call

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-2.7, monkeypatching, python-mock

I have a task

```
def task():
   a = worker()
   a.do_some_work()
```

`Worker` itself is a separate class in separate module, who use `Driver` class like that,

```
class Worker(object):
   def __init__(self):
     self.driver = Driver(args)
     ...
```

and once again `Driver` is a separate class in separate module

so when I trying something like

```
with patch('package.module.Driver', new=Mock(return_value=999)):
   task()
```

in task there is still a `Driver` class instance, but **not a mock**. That's wrong. How to fix that?

**UPD1**:
`Driver` and `Worker` live in different modules and `Worker` import `Driver`

Comment: `Driver` is a global in the module `Worker` lives in; are you patching  *that global* or where the global was imported from?

Comment: See http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html#where-to-patch

Comment: But if you are unittesting `task` you may want to just mock the whole worker..

Comment: @MartijnPieters Could I just patch only driver. It's important for me to make it work that way?

Comment: From a testing philosophy point of view you'd mock the Worker; but if patching the driver is easier, then call it an integration test and be done with it. :-)

Comment: But I trying to path it in integration test, but patching not worked. That's why I'm asking)

Comment: You didn't answer my question though; what is `package.module` here? Where does `Driver` live, and where does `Worker`?

Comment: Driver and Worker live in different modules and Worker import Driver

Comment: You are not answering my question still. :-P Is `package.module` the module of the Driver then?

Comment: @MartijnPieters you could think about it that way: Worker = MyProject.Workers.base.Worker, Driver = MyProject.utils.drivers.Driver and yes, I'm using names of modules, where class actually defined

Comment: So `package.module.Driver` here is `MyProject.utils.drivers.Driver`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60015/discussion-between-ph0en1x-and-martijn-pieters).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `MyProject.Workers.base` module imported `Driver` as a global:

```
from MyProject.utils.drivers import Driver
```

This is a *new, separate reference* to the `Driver` class. If you now patch `MyProject.utils.drivers.Driver`, the `Worker` class *will not see the patched object*; as it'll use it's own global reference.

Patch the global `Worker` actually uses:

```
with patch('MyProject.Workers.base.Driver', new=Mock(return_value=999)):
    task()
```

See the [*Where to patch* section](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html#where-to-patch) of the `mock` documentation.